# Modbus C# library unable to find FTD2XX DLL

Tags: c#, dll, modbus

I am using Nmodbus to setup an implementation, and everytime I try to run one of the instances in the code I am prompted with the following error

> unable to load DLL 'FTD2XX.dll': The specified module could not be found

I have searched through my system32 folder and copied and pasted a copy of the above DLL in there, and it is also in the folders corresponding to the C# solution. I can see it, it is there, but why am I being prompted with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you mixing 32bit code with 64bit? Try changing target from AnyCPU to 32bits.

Comment: I probably won't be of help... but, Nmodbus is not using FTD2xx.dll on its own, or is it? I'd guess you just pass SerialPort class which internally opens COM port (via FileStream) and the system itself have some problems to locate the driver/dll. Just a guess. Using USB to Serial converter?

Comment: yeah i'm using a USB-Serial converter, and I believe it is using FTD2xx since there is an FTD adapter reference into the main project solution. I am running a pre-designed sample program, just to test functionality so I can understand modbus better...

Comment: Now after adding FTD2XX dll to my SYSWOW64 folder, the new prompt I get is: **device not found** when i run the solution